# Design Solution for Metric object

Tags: design, usagemetrics

What would be the best way to track metrics for an object(Opportunity, Lead Account)?
Rn I see two ways to do that:

1. Store on Object Record(On Opportunity, On Lead)

   - Advantages

     - Easy to view on the record itself
     - No need for additional SOQL query
   - Disadvantages

     - We could hit a limit on the fields for the object
     - The object becomes messy - metrics, information about the customer would be all in one place
2. Store it on a separate Object(i.e., SLA_Metric)

   - Advantages

     - A separate object for metrics only
     - One metric could be attached to different objects, allowing to view metrics on any object. I.e., we want to view CommunicationActivity metric on Account, on Opportunity, on Quote - instead of creating new fields on each of the objects, or writing custom page to view them, we could reference SLA_Metric object to Account, Opportunity, Quote, and jump to the metrics from all of them.
     - Better sharing options - i.e. could hide the metrics from Sales Reps and make them available for the Sales Ops
   - Disadvantages

     - Need to have an additional SOQL query
     - To view the metrics of the opportuinty - need to open the SLA object itself

Any best practices advised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best practice but I have an object called "Usage_Metric__c" and a helper object called "Usage_Metric_Admin__c" Usage Metric has a picklist field, number field, and a date. The picklist is each type of metric I am tracking.

The admin object has a picklist and a query text box. A scheduled job runs each admin record to do the query and then create a new usage metric.

I have almost two years of weekly stats that feed into dashboards for the company. This is better than creating a new lead or account because then you're locked into that object. Also, everyone can see the metric records as it's just counts so it gets around any sharing issues of seeing the records if you did it the other way.